# How to change tileSize in XYZ (tileLayer) from default([256,256]) to something else for openlayers?

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3, openlayers-5, angular-openlayers, gwt-openlayers

I am trying to change the tile size for my TileLayer in openlayers and I have not been able to change it. No matter what I set the `tileSize` to be it is always `[256,256]`. Also, The files I am getting from `local_url` is 1900x1268. Below is the code.

```
var projection = get('EPSG:4326');
local_url = 'assets/tile/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';

map = new Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      source: new XYZ({
        url: this.local_url,
        projection: projection,
        wrapX: false,
        tileSize: [1024,1024]
      })
  ],
  view: new View({
    center: [0,0],
    zoom:0,
    minZoom: 0,
    maxZoom: 5,
    projection: projection
  })
});
```

Comment: You are probably seeing the tiles at the wrong zoom level so they will appear compressed.  See this example https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/xyz-esri-4326-512.html

Comment: what do  you mean by wrong zoom level ?
The XYZ source that i am using, I can only have 1 image at zoom level 0, x=0,y=0 right ? I am trying to increase the size of that image but it is not letting me exceed 256*256

Comment: In an EPSG:4326 grid the width is 2 x the height and there are usually 2 tiles at zoom 0 https://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/ESRI_Imagery_World_2D/MapServer/tile/0/0/0
https://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/ESRI_Imagery_World_2D/MapServer/tile/0/0/1

Comment: So there is no way to customize the tile size ? I can only have it 256*256 ?

Comment: Yes, see the example I linked in the first comment https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/xyz-esri-4326-512.html

Comment: @Mike i  tried opening the url u shared but could not do so, there's a 404 error. Can you reshare the link?

Comment: @JalajYadav_Avesta The example has been removed because ESRI has removed that service

Comment: @Mike you mentined that 512*512 cannot be acheived in Openlayers when using XYZ to create the source for a layer, but i was able to do that. Just specifying tileSize worked for me. Using Openlayer 7.x.x

Comment: @JalajYadav_Avesta That will not change the size of the tiles being served.  If they are not served at 512 they will be displayed at the wrong scale.

Comment: @Mike i have configured the console of the 3rd party to serve 512 tiles and i have specified the same in my URL. So will it work properly then. Cause it is.